# WCF 2 Method with same name

Tags: c#, wcf

i have a short question to a wcf Service

I want to implement 2 Methods with the same name.
But with a different amount of Parameter.

Example

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILiveLeadsService
{                
    [OperationContract]
    string AddLiveLeads(string a, string b);

    [OperationContract]
    string AddLiveLeads(string a, string b, string c);
}
```

What can i do that i can use this 2 Methods with the same name?

cheers
Andre

Comment: _"What can i do"_ - try to use the search. :) Alternatively you can use a Data Transfer Object with properties and evaluate the properties in the method, as opposed to creating various overloads.

Comment: Hello CodeCaster

im not very familiar with the WFC Services..
Can you give me a more specific example to the transfer object? Im not sure for what i have to searchhere..

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189019/are-request-response-parameter-wrappers-good-practice, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273127(v=vs.100).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn132654.aspx